# How to convert DFS algorithm using recursion to algorithm with normal iteration?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have implemented successfully DFS (Deep First Search) Algorithm by using recursion but I dont know how to use normal iteration instead.

Below is my code with recursive calls.

```
data[1000][1000];
mark[1000][1000];// The array marks vertex visited
void dfs(int x, int y, int label){

    if(x < 0 || x == SIZE)
        return;
    if(y < 0 || y == SIZE)
        return;

    if(data[x][y] == 0 || mark[x][y] != 0)
        return;

    mark[x][y] = label;

    dfs(x + 1, y, label);
    dfs(x, y + 1, label);
    dfs(x - 1, y, label);
    dfs(x, y - 1, label);
}
```

Please help me convert recursion to loops like for or while.
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a new structure and use stack. `make_tuple(int x,int y,int label)` returns tuple type.

```
typedef struct
{
    int x,y,label;
} tuple;

stack<tuple > s;
s.push(make_tuple(initialx,initialy,initiallabel));

while(!s.empty())
{
    tuple p = s.top();
    s.pop();
    int x = p.x;
    int y = p.y;
    int label = p.label;


    if(x < 0 || x == SIZE)
        continue;
    if(y < 0 || y == SIZE)
        continue;
    if(data[x][y] == 0 || mark[x][y] != 0)
        continue;
    mark[x][y] = label;
    s.push(make_tuple(x + 1, y, label));
    s.push(make_tuple(x, y + 1, label));
    s.push(make_tuple(x - 1, y, label));
    s.push(make_tuple(x, y - 1, label));
}
```

Comment: Actually my problem I am doing is to count how many areas are there in the array. The collection of cells = 1 is an area. Each area is assigned by specific number: 1, 2,3 ....
The require of the problems are only use for/while loop. Do not use high data like struct, stack, queue and even recursive calls. My idea to resolve this problem is using DFS but I just know to use recursive algorithm. Anyways, I'd like to thank you. Could you give me another advice?

Comment: Stack is a generalised way to implement DFS using looping. In recursion u pass arguments, so in stack also you have to pass arguments. If these arguments are more than one, then u have to make structure to pass these arguments.

Comment: I think it is not easy to implement DFS without using stack, queue, and recursive. Can you post the original problem? Maybe there is a way to solve it without using DFS.

Comment: @LongUni You're really asking a different question now, so it would probably be best to make this answer the 'accepted' answer and post a new question, but gloompisces is correct - DFS can, AFAIK, only be implemented using a stack or recursion - you should probably forget DFS and try to approach the problem differently (and post the original problem statement in your new question).

Comment: @LongUni You can mark this as accepted so that it may help if someone hits this question in future.